# href of Link same as src of iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe, src

I was wondering to do trough javascript a check if the src of an iframe is the same as the href of the given link so that if they are equal to set the class to current

Of course I don't really know Javascript this well but it would be great

```
<script>
changeclass() {
var iframesrc =  document.getElementById("videobox").contentWindow.location.href
if(iframesrc=###a.href###) {
    var linknumber = ###a.href;
    document.getElementById("linknumber").className = "current";
}

}
</script>
<a name="link1" href="samelink" class="current">Video 1</a>
<a name="link2" href="different link" class="">Video 2</a>
<a name="link3" href="different link" class="">Video 3</a>

<iframe name="videobox" src="samelink">
```

Thanks, Im sorry for not having the smallest idea of how to do javascript into my code.

Comment: Then you probably should google a bit.

Comment: Okay, what have you tried?

Comment: How to change class on href link equal to iframe src

Comment: That's what you are trying to achieve. **What have you tried?**

Comment: I have tried, I just knew it was all wrong probably ,I edited the question

Comment: Since you are new to javascript coding (and more importantly, new to coding in general, it seems), IMO it's not going to do much good trying to explain to you where you went wrong / what you need to do. IMO you need to step back and learn the basics of javascript first.  As an alternative, I would recommend you look into 3rd party video handling scripts that make it easy for you to just copy/paste and do some easy configuration.  Or, hire someone to do this for you. Because, it would be far easier for others to just write some working code for you, but that's not what this site is about.

Comment: Be nicer and explain how can I get href of a link with some class please thanks

Comment: I wasn't trying to be mean, just realistic. There are several ways to get the href of a link based on a class. Look into `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` for starters. Once you have the reference to the link, you can use the `href` property or `.getAttribute('href')` method. My overall point was that it's hard to give you directions to where you wanna go when you don't even know how to drive. This was not meant to be taken as an insult, and I'm sorry if you took it as such.

Comment: @MicaButu : TO which u need to set the active class, iframe or anchor tag

Comment: @MicaButu : Posted the answer, is that what you were expecting

Comment: @M-S Thankyou so much, It works , its just doing it before it targets the iframe but I think I can fix this , thankyou so much this is the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you are expecting:

HTML:

```
<a name="link1" href="samelink" class="current">Video 1</a>
<a name="link2" href="different link" class="">Video 2</a>
<a name="link3" href="different link" class="">Video 3</a>

<iframe id="videobox" name="videobox" src="samelink">
```

JS:

```
var iframesrc =  document.getElementById("videobox");
var ahref = document.querySelectorAll("a");
var iframePath = iframesrc.getAttribute("src");
for(var i=0;i<ahref.length;i++){
   var fhref = ahref[i].getAttribute("href");
    if(iframePath == fhref){
       var classActive = ahref[i].className = "activeLink";
        console.log(classActive);
    }
}
```